# How to introspect input and output buffers

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a transport is too slow, I would expect the output buffer of the publisher to fill up, and would like to check if this is happening in a running system.  Is there a way to check this using something in rqt or on the command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217420/how-to-introspect-input-and-output-buffers/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could instrument your code to expose this information but introspection of the queue usage is not visible externally by default.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-10-20**:
Thanks! In hindsight this is not terribly surprising.  Do you know offhand of a nice way to instrument for this?